# Buffer overflow in C with gets

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I am very new to C and as a class assignment my instructor wanted us to play with buffer overflows. I found the following online as an example and I can't figure out how to use it!

```
#include <stdio.h>
char temp[32];

unsigned int setThis=1;

printf("Enter your temp: \n");
fgets(temp, 34, stdin); //Takes a 34 buffer size when temp can only be 32
printf("Value of you setThis: %d", setThis);
```

So my question is, how do i set "setThis" to a certain variable?
 Any help is appreciated, BeastlyJman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guaranteed way to do it, but typically variables are put on the stack such that the first variable is last in memory. So if you declare `setThis` *before* `temp[32]`, then `setThis` will be at the end of the `temp` array, and you can overwrite it.

But as I said, there's no guarantee that's what the compiler will do. You should really check the assembly code that the compiler generates to see where `temp` and `setThis` are located.

Also, you can save yourself some typing if you reduce the size of `temp` to `temp[8]` and then pass `10` to `fgets`. To cause an overflow, you need to type more characters than the buffer can hold.